# urxvt - tab expand environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, tab-completion, urxvt, rxvt

I am new to urxvt (moved from gnome-terminal -> Ubuntu 12.04 refugee). I am used to having environment variables expand in gnome-terminal by default

Suppose that I have an environment variable "FOO_PATH" set up for "/home/foo/".

When I type $FOO_PATH/ , I do not get an expansion and/or a listing of items in $FOO_PATH.

How do I achieve this in {u}rxvt ?
Thanks for your attention.

RRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a shell issue, and nothing that has to do with Urxvt/Gnome Terminal. Probably Bash is used in both cases - perhaps you are missing the `bash-completion` package or an equivalent in your current setup (it seems like you have left Ubuntu, but you don't say what you use now, so I can't give more specific tips). Try installing that.

Comment: I have not left Ubuntu. I moved from GNOME to XFCE. I think you are right about $bash-completion$. I am not the admin and it seems to be the result of a botched upgrade from 10.04->12.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is about `direxpand` option. `$ shopt -s direxpand` and `$FOO_PATH/` will be expanded by `TAB`.

Comment: (eleven years passed...*:-) I've used `cdable_vars` for years and I noticed only today that `bash_completion` must be activated after `shopt -s cdable_vars`. If you set it after reading the completion block, variables are not expanded...