# bash: variable name not being expanded with Tab completion

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, environment-variables

On a remote computer with bash version "3.2.51(1)-release" (OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.1 (x86_64)), I could not do a usual tab completion with variable name. for example, I'd like to type:

```
echo $OLDPWD/
```

then at the end of the slash, I can hit "Tab" and the variable name would be expanded to the old directory name (before the last `cd` or `pushd` command). This works in my own laptop (Debian 7, Bash 4.2.37(1)-release). Why in this SLES bash shell it would not work?

Similarly, if I type

```
echo $OLDP
```

and then hit "Tab" at the end of the "P" there, bash would complete that to `$OLDPWD`. This would not happen in SLES 11 bash too.

What control variables (shopt? set?) that affect this behavior?

Comment: Does Alt+$ work?

Comment: Probably the older bash version does not have all the fancy completion functions included. Can you install the `bash-completion` package on the remote machine?

Comment: @glennjackman: The `bash-completion` package provides a set of wrappers around many commands that customize the argument completion behavior for those commands. It does not affect the completion of environment variables. That capability is built into later versions of bash.

Comment: Is $OLDPWD set?  In my bash 4.2.25 it is not defined until you've used `cd` at least once.  I don't know if bash 3.x set $OLDPWD when you did cd.  Does completion of, say, $HOM<tab> complete to $HOME?

Comment: by the way, I just found in csh, if I set `set zzz='~/some/dir'`, I can not do tab expansion for `cp $zzz +tab` but If I define by `set zzz=~/some/dir`, I can do the expansion. Looks like the shell cannot expand after string in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

`shopt -s direxpand` will make `echo $HOME/<tab>` expand to `echo /home/matt/` in bash 4.2.  In bash 4.1 it should be the default.

I find that `bash-completion` can really mess things up.  I always either uninstall `bash-completion` or run `complete -r` to make sure that the individual completion rules aren't doing something stupid to the default completions.

If `$OLDPWD` is actually set then `echo $OLDP<tab>` should expand to `echo $OLDPWD`.  I don't know what would keep that from happening.

Comment: How do we do it in csh? I see 'shopt: Command not found.'.

Answer (score 0):

Try `C-x $` instead of `TAB` to explicitly request possible variable (not something else) completions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer for 
[urxvt - tab expand environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/434139/urxvt-tab-expand-environment-variables) by Dmitry Alexandrov.

> "This is about direxpand option.
>
> $ shopt -s direxpand and $FOO_PATH/
>
> will be expanded by TAB"