# How do I ensure bash *never* expands paths in environment variables when tab-completing?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, environment-variables, terminal.app

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I normally using the above bash version on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine via MATE terminal. Currently however I am using macOS 10.14.6's Terminal.app to SSH in to that machine. The `.bash_profile` for my user just `source`s `.bashrc` so there shouldn't be any configuration differences beside the terminal emulators.

I have environment variables that I use to abbreviate frequently-used but long directory paths, defined in my .bashrc, something like:

```
export FOO=~/foo/bar/baz
export BAR=~/foo/bar/baz/qux/foobar
```

I have a habit of using tab-completion (I mean typing part of the name and pressing the tab key) on subdirectories of these variables, so I can type:

`cd $FOO/mi<TAB>`

and get:

`cd $FOO/misc/`

This is the behaviour under the MATE terminal that I am used to and like. But using Terminal.app to SSH in to the same machine, it irritatingly expands the variable:

`cd /home/andrea/foo/bar/baz/misc/`

I don't know why this happens, but I suspect Terminal.app sends a different escape sequence. If I type `<ESC><TAB>` in Terminal.app instead of `<TAB>`, I get the familiar and desired behaviour (no expansion of the environment variable). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Terminal.app's escape sequence *for TAB* is configurable.

So, I want to know if I can force bash to always use the behaviour I want.

In the answers to [bash: variable name not being expanded with Tab completion](https://superuser.com/questions/604109/bash-variable-name-not-being-expanded-with-tab-completion) (where someone has the **opposite** problem to me, they want to have the behaviour that I **don't** want), I have seen `shopt -s direxpand`. So I tried its inverse, `shopt -u direxpand`, and it did not help. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418493/bash-variable-expansion-on-tab-complete I saw also `shopt -s cdable_vars`, but likewise `shopt -u cdable_vars` did not help.

I am at a loss. :(

Comment: Rather than trying randomly suggested shopt variables, have you tried comparing the full list of shopt option values from both terminals to see the differences? There aren't that many of them and you can get the full list by writing `shopt` with no arguments. Their use cases are explained here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html 
I believe that's either the fastest way to solution or to the knowledge if shopt options are the culprit.

Comment: @MarekRost I read that and it doesn't help. It does seem like `direxpand` should be what I want, yet it doesn't seem to do anything.